# How to avoid Pandas Groupby key error when a GroupBy object might not contain a certain key

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some analysis over a dataframe, with one of the columns being an integer with values either 0 or 1 (Sort of boolean, but in integer form). It looks something like this:

```
  Nat. | Result
-------|-------
  CA   |  1
  USA  |  0
  GB   |  1
  USA  |  1
  CA   |  0
  GB   |  1
```

I grouped the data according to the nationality column, and one of the values (GB in the example above) produced -by chance- a group whose all members were only 1. This have created a problem because I have a function that I call a lot that contains group_obj.get_group(0) and this causes a runtime error "KeyError: 0"

My question: I want to create the logic that follows:

```
if (group_obj contains key 0):
   return group_obj.get_group(0)
else:
   print "Group Object contains no 0s"
   return null
```

Thanks

I am using Python2, Pandas and iPython Notebook.

Comment: You can get all the values for a specific group level `group_obj.get_level_values(level_name)` to avoid this kind of error

Comment: If you only want to get values with 0's, you can do something like `df[df['Result'] == 0]`, which will work if there are no zeros as well

Comment: @Jezzamon, although this can work, I wanted something more generic. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @EdChum, it seems that I do not understand well the get_level_values, I will have to read more about it (I got an error when I passed level 0). I have posted how I managed to solve it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about just `try` - `except` ?

Comment: I feel like `get_group()` should come with a parameter that addresses this problem, maybe a `fillna` param like other methods have

Answer (score 8):

OK, so here is how I was able to do it:

```
if key1 in group_obj.groups.keys():
    #Do processing
```

so, the keys() method in a groupby object stores already the available keys and it can be accessed directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `value_counts`, unstack the result to get the results in columns and then use `fillna(0)` to replace all NaNs.

```
>>> df.groupby('Nationality').Result.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
Result       0  1
Nationality      
CA           1  1
GB           0  2
USA          1  1
```

Comment: thanks; that can work I guess. I have found another method group_obj.groups.keys(), and that gave me directly the keys and I was able to process after that. I have posted this method as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get a group from a groupby object and get an empty data frame instead of an error if the group doesn't exist is this:

```
def get_group(key, dataframe_group):
    if key in dataframe_group.groups.keys():
        return dataframe_group.get_group(key)
    else:
        original_df = dataframe_group.obj
        return original_df.drop(original_df.index)
```

Basically, checking first if the keys exists in the group and they if it doesn't get the original data frame but without any contents.